# Is Stugeron (Cinnarazine) Available Without Prescription in Argentina?

Tags: health, argentina, drugs

Title says it all.

Searching found an Argentine firm ([Janssen](https://www.janssen.com/argentina/productos)) that imports the drug Stugeron (Cinnarazine) to Argentina, but I saw no information there or anywhere else about availability or restriction.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 
Stugeron (and all the other brands of Cinnarazine) sell as ["Venta bajo receta"](https://www.janssen.com/argentina/sites/www_janssen_com_argentina/files/product/pdf/stugeron_forte_ccds_mar-13.pdf).
 
Which you'd guess means that it requires a prescription, but... it doesn't, [unless you are trying to get your insurance to cover for it](https://www.educativo.net/articulos/los-medicamentos-y-sus-diferentes-condiciones-de-venta-470.html).
Drugs that say "Venta bajo receta archivada", on the other hand, do require a prescription in every case.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your response.Interesting article!