# Do Water Chestnuts Exist in Colombia?

Tags: food-and-drink, colombia, bogota

Do water chestnuts grow in Colombia? Or is it possible to buy them there? I'm assisting a film crew that's on location for a cooking documentary, and they would like to blend an asian fusion dish with local Colombian ingredients. Unfortunately, they do not speak the local language and are having a hard time finding water chestnuts in Bogotá.

Comment: Are any local Colombian cooks participating in the documentary? They'd know.

Comment: Is searching for "castaña de agua Bogotá" not working for you?

Comment: Just searching for that came up with Prodelagro and some other places. It seems like this is the sort of question that could be asked about any food, so I am not sure it has much to do with Bogotá. Bogotá has a population of 7 million and a good number of international restaurants, so I suspect that you will be able to find almost anything you could want. Hiring a translator or even just using the Google translate app with a cook from a Chinese restaurant would probably work too, but an Internet search should be quite sufficient.

Comment: I don’t know, but “it is grown in many countries.”  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleocharis_dulcis. 
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleocharis_dulcis

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, You recently sought help in [finding pharmaceutical drugs in Argentina](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144506/is-stugeron-cinnarazine-available-without-prescription-in-argentina) in this forum. Let's try to empathize with and help each other as we travel.

Comment: Fair criticism, AnthumChris. I'll withdraw my close vote. Now...how about my first comment above: are any Colombian cooks participating? Does your film crew _know_ any Columbian cooks? Have any of your crew gone into a restaurant or market and just asked? All Stacks look for question posters to have done some research before asking, and to report in their question what they've tried.